# Almost maximal subgroup by cyclic supplement

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

This question is related to my previous post. Let $ S_{4} $ is the symmetric group of degree $ 4 $ and $ A_{4} $ is the alternating. $ S_{3} $ is a maximal subgroup of $ S_{4} $ and $ C_{3} $ is a maximal subgroup of $ A_{4} $ that $ C_{3} $ is the cyclic group of order $ 3 $. are there $ y \in S_{4} $ and $ x \in A_{4} $ such that $ S_{4} = \langle y \rangle S_{3} $ and $ A_{4} = \langle x \rangle C_{3} $ ?

Comment: Just to clarify, by $\langle z\rangle K$, do you mean $K+z K+\dots$ or the subgroup generated by such?

Comment: @Chanler $ \langle z \rangle K$ do mean subgroup generated,

Answer (score 1):

We have that $(1234)S_3=S_4$. This can be seen by a counting argument as follows. We have that $S_3\cap yS_3=\varnothing$, by considering such an elements effect on $4$. Thus $S_3+yS_3+y^2S_3+y^3S_3\subset S_4$ is of order $4|S_3|=4*3!=4!$, so that the inclusion is equality.

Such an equality cannot exist for $A_4$ though, since all elements of $A_4$ have order $3$ or less, so that $|\langle x\rangle C_3|\le 9<12$. That said, the subgroup generated by $\langle (12)(34)\rangle C_3=A_4$. This can be seen as follows. The order of the product of two elements is atleast the $lcm$ of there individual orders. Thus our $(\langle (12)(34)\rangle C_3)$ contains an element of order $6$. Such a subgroup would be normal, since it would be of index $2$. But $A_4$ is simple so it must be the whole group.

Comment: But it is true for $ \langle (1,2,3,4) \rangle S_{3} $?